# AWS Opensearch: Data Nodes vs Instance type cost differences

Tags: amazon-ec2, opensearch

I'm just having cpu 100% issues on opensearch, and I was thinking about two ways to solve this issue.

The first one should be trying to increase my data nodes in opensearch from 1 to 2, to see how it goes.
The second one is to increase the instance type from m5.large to m5.xlarge.

I currently have two questions regarding this.

1. What should be the cost differences between these? (I know m5.xlarge is double the cost of m5.large, but I don't know the cost of the data node)
2. What do you think it's the best way to solve Opensearch's cpu and ram running at 100%?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly is causing the load.

Start by enabling search and indexing slow logs, look at the thread pools graphs.

Also, look at the [Tune for indexing speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) and [Tune for search speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html) docs, they have some good insights.

Generally, scaling horizontally (adding more machines into the cluster) would help with concurrent requests while scaling vertically (increasing machine size) - with rare but heavy queries.